# Why does this API print a log on as output when I make a get request?

Tags: python, api, pycharm

I am using PyCharm and when I make a get request, I get this message in red text:

```
30-Jun-19 11:32:21 DEBUG     Starting new HTTPS connection (1): eodhistoricaldata.com:443
30-Jun-19 11:32:21 DEBUG     https://eodhistoricaldata.com:443 "GET /api/real-time/AAL.US?api_token=MYAPIKEY&fmt=json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
```

Another example is :

```
30-Jun-19 11:32:12 INFO      POST Request: https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/MYACCOUNTINFO/Messages.json
```

Other APIs I use will make calls silently and others will  display this red text(INFO, DEBUG, etc)

So what is this red text and how can I have it not printing to my console?

Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with the PyCharm. PyCharm is an IDE, not an API. I think you are mixing things here. The red text is the `cerr` stream, black is the `cout` stream. PyCharm has no influence on what is on there, it simply displays those.

Comment: Yeah I didn't mean that it was a PyCharm thing, but I am not sure what a cerr stream is. How do I get that to not display like the cout?

Comment: Although the default answer to that question should be 'google it', here you go: Every command line application has a three streams: cin (Input), cout (Output), cerr (Errors/Status messages). How do you hide it? Simple answer: You don't. The cerr stream is valuable and important and shouldn't be hidden. How to get rid of the DEBUG/INFO messages? That is the actual question, and you have to read the docs of the API that you use. But as you don't specify that here, I don't think that question can be answered.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer so I will post for future people to see:

```
import logging

logging.disable()
```